# Delphi-OpenCV - pixel values of cvMat or PIplImage

Tags: delphi, opencv

I am using Delphi-OpenCV and unlike the advanced functions, like object detection etc, I am not able to achieve a fairly simple thing - read pixel values from a PIplImage, or a pCvMat.

Since there is pretty much no documentation for Delphi-OpenCV, I experimented a lot, but the closest I can get is a few nonsenses, or opencv core dll errors when trying to fill a TCvScalar by a multitude of different approaches.

I have a 8bit, 1 channel jpg picture and need to provide a pixel coordinates and get its value like this in C++ :

```
Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x);
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **TocvImage** class over your **pIplImage** image, for example:

```
var
  image: pIplImage;
  img: TocvImage;
  px: TocvPixel;
begin
  image:= cvLoadImage(c_str('d:\IMAG0132.jpg'),CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
  img := TocvImage.Create(image);
  px := img.Pixel[100,100];
  img.Free;
end;
```

Or see TocvImage.GetPixel function as reference how to directly read pixel information from pIplImage.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!